# Question on surfaces where opposite sides of a rectangle have equal length

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I'm trying to solve [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=qNBYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=show+that+under+these+conditions+there+is+a+parameter+transformation+differential+geometry&source=bl&ots=CYtoVmP8wn&sig=4GYltoKgS6FojtXfl47L-R7UBCE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi26_O-sYvSAhVFcBoKHU4DCEgQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=show%20that%20under%20these%20conditions%20there%20is%20a%20parameter%20transformation%20differential%20geometry&f=false) exercise from Kühnel.

Let $f: [0, A] \times [0, B] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a parametrized surface element. Show that the following conditions (1) and (2) are equivalent:

1. For each rectangle $R = [u_1, u_1 + a] \times [u_2, u_2 + b] \subset U$, the opposite sides of $f(R)$ are of equal length.
2. One has $\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial u_2} = \frac{\partial g_{22}}{\partial u_1} = 0$ in all of $U$. ($g_{ij}$ are the matrix entries of the first fundamental form)

I've solved (2) $\implies$ (1) and after much trying, I don't know how to prove the other implication.

Kühnel further asks to prove that under these conditions, there is a parameter transformation $\varphi: U \rightarrow \tilde{U}$ such that for $\tilde{f} = f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ the first fundamental form can be written as:

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & \cos \vartheta \\
  \cos \vartheta & 1
 \end{pmatrix}

and I don't see how this follows from setting $\varphi(u_1, u_2) = \left( \int \sqrt{g_{11}} du_1, \int \sqrt{g_{22}} du_2 \right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS**: (1) Suppose $\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial u_2}>0$ on some open set containing $[a,a+h]\times [b,b+k]$. Show that the length of $f\big([a,a+h]\times\{b+k\}\big)$ is greater than the length of $f\big([a,a+h]\times\{b\}\big)$.

(2) If you set $(u'_1,u'_2) = \phi(u_1,u_2)$, what is the length of $\partial\tilde f/\partial u'_1$?

Comment: If $\alpha (t) = (t, b+k)$ and $\beta (t) = (t, b)$ are the sides of the rectangle, their lengths on the curve are $\int_a^{a+h} \sqrt{g_{11}(\alpha (t))} dt$, and $\int_a^{a+h} \sqrt{g_{11}(\beta (t))} dt$, respectively. I don't see how one can use the fact that $\frac{\partial g_{11}}{\partial u_2} > 0$ to show that they are different.

Comment: Remember what a positive derivative tells you!

Comment: That the function is increasing... So?

Comment: So compare those two integrals!

Comment: What did you just tell me about $g_{11}(t,b+k)$ and $g_{11}(t,b)$?

Comment: $g_{11}(t, b + k)$ must be greater than $g_{11}(t,b)$ for all $t$. Ok, thank you.